# Transform excel column filled with numbers into a special format

Tags: excel, format

I have two excel worksheets. In one there a column with an id in the format E-12345 and in the other one a column with normal numbers 12345. And those refer to the same case.

Another example: E-00093 is the same is as 93 in the other sheet.

I know need to format the simple number column into the E-12345 format but I have no clue how to do it. Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Select the column and use the context menu for formatting.

As macro code:

```
Sub formatMe()
'
' Makro1 formatMe
'
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
End Sub
```